# Memory limit exceeded when running very simple query in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a very large table (730M rows) that uses the `ReplacingMergeTree` engine. I've started getting "Memory limit (for query) exceeded" even when running trivial queries.

For example, `SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5` gives:

```
Code: 241. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded: would use 24.50 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 26009509376 bytes), maximum: 9.31 GiB: While executing MergeTree.
```

Why is Clickhouse trying to use 24.5G of memory for a simple SELECT query, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this looks like a ClickHouse disadvantage... However, there is a way to get around this limitation, I use a query on **system.tables** table, there is a **partition_key** field.

```
SELECT partition_key FROM system.tables 
WHERE database = 'your_db' AND name='your_big_table'
```

It indicates what partition key the table has, or rather how parts of the table can be addressed. Since the table is large, there are probably partitions and we can use them:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_db.your_big_table
WHERE toYYYYMM(event_time) = toYYYYMM(now())
LIMIT 5;
```

or if it is intDiv(id_value, 10000000)

```
SELECT *
FROM your_db.your_big_table
WHERE intDiv(id_value, 10000000) = 0
LIMIT 5;
```

This way you reduce the number of rows to iterate and bypass the limitation.
I think LIMIT is not transmitted to the nodes of the CH cluster and that is why such an overhead occurs, and you got the exception.

By the way, I have the same story because of the limitation in max_rows_to_read_leaf

```
 DB::Exception: Limit for rows (controlled by 'max_rows_to_read_leaf' setting) exceeded
```

Answer (score -1):

Because many parallel threads read all columns and 65k rows and allocate several MB for each column.

How many columns in the table?

Try

```sql
set max_block_size=512, max_threads=1, max_rows_to_read=512;
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5;
```